# How to refresh the Table View Data in Titanium Studio

Tags: ios, search, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I've created an app using tabBar. I've created a separate search Window Containing a searchBar and a TableView to display the recent search items. Whenever the return event is fired a new window called searchresult.js opens up displaying the data searched. When I click on the back button it goes from searchresult.js-->searchpage.js, but the problem is the table for recent data gets updated in the database but it isn't showing on the table and I've to go to the main page and open the searchpage.js again to see the correct data... Pls help...Thanx in advance

I've used the following code: searchpage.js

```
    //*** Search Field ***
            var search = Titanium.UI.createSearchBar({
                barColor:'#000', 
                showCancel:true,
                height:43,
                hintText:'Name of the part you want to search',
                autocorrect:true,
                top:0,
            });

            content.add(search);


            //*** Table For Recent Search ***

            var db = Titanium.Database.install('car.db','dbversion1');

            var sql = db.execute ('SELECT * FROM search_history ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0, 10');


            var data = [];
            while (sql.isValidRow()){

                var searchQuery = sql.fieldByName('search_query');
                var selectedCategory = sql.fieldByName('selected_category');
                var searchID = sql.fieldByName ('id');

                data.push({title: searchQuery});
                sql.next();
            }   
            var searchTable = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
                headerTitle:'RECENT SEARCH',
                data: data,

            });
            Ti.API.info(searchTable.title);
            content.add(searchTable);


            //Search Action

                search.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
                    Titanium.API.info('search bar:blur received');
                });

                search.addEventListener('cancel', function(e) {
                    Titanium.API.info('search bar:cancel received');
                    search.blur();
                });

            search.addEventListener('return', function(e){
            var insertSql = db.execute('INSERT INTO search_history (search_query, selected_category) VALUES ("' + search.value + '", 1)');   
                var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
                    backgroundColor:'#ffffff',
                    url:'searchresult.js',
                    title: 'Search Result',
                    searchValue: search.value
                });
                Ti.API.info(search.value);

                search.blur();
                Titanium.UI.currentTab.open(win, {animation:true});
            });

    // Back Button Action
    bckButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            if (Ti.Android){
                        win.close();
                    }else{
                        win.close({animated:true});
        }
        });
```

and searchresult.js

```
    // *** Content ***
            var content = Titanium.UI.createView({
                backgroundColor:'#fff',
                height:'100%',
                width:'100%',
                layout:'vertical'
            });
            wrapper.add(content);

            var searchQuery = win.searchValue;

            var db = Titanium.Database.install('car.db', 'dbversion1');

            var sql = db.execute ("SELECT * FROM part_category WHERE part_name LIKE \'%"+ searchQuery +"%\'");

            var data = [];

            while(sql.isValidRow()){
                var partName = sql.fieldByName ('part_name');
                var partID = sql.fieldByName ('id');

                data.push({title: partName, hasChild:true, id:partID, url:'partsubcategory.js'});
                sql.next()
            };

            var resultTable = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
                data : data,
            });

            content.add(resultTable);


    // Back Button Action
        bckButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){

            if (Ti.Android){
                        win.close();
                    }else{
                        win.close({animated:true});
        }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you should save the search results in a data structure and fire an event after the search is complete. Any other tables that you want to update should be listening for that event and update when it recieves the event.

I believe there is an example of this in the training documentation for tiBountyHunter

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/Event_Handling